# Why does the image is not showing correctly using CSS?

Tags: php, css

I am new in learning web development especially in PHP and using CSS. The image that I have has 2560 × 1600. Is that size already enough to cover your background entirely? I only intended to put 1 background image but when I run the code, it will show as if there are 2 images.

Below is a snippet of my output.

[image]

Here is my CSS code:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5)), url(images/wp2330460.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: What do you want is not repeatin the image as background image?

Comment: Yes, I want it to show as 1 image only.

Comment: My answer should fix your problem with your image repeating

Comment: you need to add `html{min-height:100%}`

Comment: If you want to disable repeating you can add `background-repeat: no-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

If your background-size is set to **cover** it shouldn't repeat. But, if the container is larger than the image and background-size is set to **fit** it will repeat unless background-repeat is set to **no-repeat**.

Anyway, here's the code that shows how to repeat your image on purpose first. Then don't repeat it afterward.

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 4.5rem;
}
.background-repeat {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 2000px;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuEMz.jpg);
    background-size: fit;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.background-no-repeat {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 2000px;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuEMz.jpg);
    background-size: fit;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-repeat">
  <h1>This Background Image will Repeat</h1>
</div>

<div class="background-no-repeat">
    <h1>This Background Image will NOT Repeat</h1>
</div>
```